# scala dateTime weird results

Tags: scala, datetime, timestamp

I am getting unexpected results when I am running this code:

```
  var  DateFormat_in = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var  DateFormat_out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
  var m ="4/29/2016 12:12:12"
  println(str_timestamp(m,DateFormat_in,DateFormat_out)) // third
  def str_timestamp(date_str:String,format_in:SimpleDateFormat,format_out: SimpleDateFormat): DateTime =
    {
     val date = format_in.parse(date_str)
     val date_modified_str = format_out.format(date)
     println(date_modified_str) // first
     val temp = format_out.parse(date_modified_str);
     println(temp)     // second 
     val dateTime: DateTime = new DateTime(temp.getTime)
     dateTime
    }
```

I am getting the following:

> 2016-12-29 12:12:12
>
> Fri Jan 29 12:12:12 CET 2016
>
> 2016-01-29T12:12:12.000+01:00

why the month is changing from one to one ? How to get it right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please consult the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The correct pattern symbol for months is "M" (capital letter) and for minutes "m" (small).